# Mechanize memory leak despite setting history size to 0 and clearing history

Tags: ruby, memory, memory-leaks, mechanize, mechanize-ruby

Here is an example script that reproduces the issue

```
require 'mechanize'

agent = Mechanize.new
agent.history.max_size = 0 

5000.times do |i| 
  agent.get('http://www.yahoo.com')
  agent.history.clear

  p `ps -o rss -p #{$$}`.strip.split.last.to_i * 1024 # Prints out memory usage of the ruby process
end
```

I'm doing both `agent.history.max_size` and `agent.history.clear` but it seems that memory usage is increasing with each loop.

Here is the output showing increasing memory usage (starts at 48MB and increases by 1-2MB with every loop).

```
48603136
50274304
51470336
53260288
54984704
55836672
56799232
57884672
59150336
60358656
61349888
62193664
...
```

How do I get Mechanize to stop leaking memory?

Comment: Does the behaviour change if you create a new agent in each iteration instead of reusing the same agent multiple times?

Comment: No change, still see the same increase in memory size as above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not a memory leak, some things just haven't been gc'ed yet. Put:

```
GC.start
```

in the loop if you feel like you need it, otherwise it's probably safe to ignore.

Comment: Thanks. Putting `GC.start` at the end of the loop fixed things.